# MAC Address Convention

Tags: mac-address

I need help understanding MAC address convention as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#Address_details). If I understand it correctly, then MAC address **00-27-C7-38-42-11**:

1. Has 00 as the most significant byte.
2. Has 0 (zero) set in its least significant bit of the most significant byte -- 00 Hex is 0000 0000 in binary.
3. And therefore it's universally administered.

While MAC address **A9-5E-4C-22-AF-17**:

1. Has A9 as the most significant byte.
2. Has 1 (one) set in its least significant bit of the most significant byte -- A9 Hex is 1010 1001 in binary.
3. And therefore it's locally administered.

With that;

1. Is my understanding correct?
2. The the above MAC addresses are all 6 bytes and contain no unicast/multicast bit field. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I understand it correctly, then MAC address 00-27-C7-38-42-11
>
> 1. Has 00 as the most significant byte.
> 2. Has 0 (zero) set in its least significant bit of the most
>      significant byte -- 00 Hex is 0000 0000 in binary.
> 3. And therefore it's universally administered.

It's the **second least significant bit**, not the least significant bit. It's still 0. So it is indeed universally administered (globally unique).

---

> While MAC address A9-5E-4C-22-AF-17:
>
> 1. Has A9 as the most significant byte.
> 2. Has 1 (one) set in its least significant bit of the most significant byte -- D9 Hex is 1010 1001 in binary.
> 3. And therefore it's locally administered.

You mean A9, not D9. Yes, A9 is 101010*0*1 in binary.

Again, it's the second least significant bit. Which is still 0 (I marked it between asterisks above). It's universally administered (globally unique).

---

> The the above MAC addresses are all 6 bytes and contain no
>   unicast/multicast bit field. Is this correct?

They both contain the Unicast/Multicast bit, naturally. This is where the least significant bit of the most significant octet (byte) enters into play.

- The first address is unicast. The least significant bit of the most significant octet is 0.
- The second address is multicast. 1010100*1* has 1 as the least significant bit.

Hope this helps.